# Where i can find list of Raspberry home automation platforms and projects?

Tags: home-automation

I'm unix newbie and planning to start my own home automation project.

Where i can find list of Raspberry home automation platforms and projects so i could compare what way i should do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples in the  [MagPi](http://www.themagpi.com/) .  Also adverts for automation equipment.